# How to redirect to a Rails controller from inside an Engine controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a Rails 4.2 app & I'm inside a controller action of a Rails engine such as AlchemyCMS.  I want to redirect from inside the engine controller to a Rails error handling controller.

I tried:

```
redirect_to controller: 'ErrorsController', action: 'show', status: 404
```

unfortunately the application looks for a controller in the engine namespace and returns something like:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"alchemy/ErrorsController", :locale=>"en", :urlname=>"more"}

Comment: `controller: '::ErrorsController'` might work

Comment: or `redirect_to controller: '/errors', action: 'show', status: 404`

Answer (score 1):

You can raise error in your engine controller and rescue it inside application_controller.rb file of your app:

```
rescue_from YourRaisedException do |exception|
  redirect_to controller: 'ErrorsController', action: 'show', status: 404
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The most Rails-y way to do this would be to create a route entry in your `config/routes.rb` file, then use the `_url` helper in your controller (for a redirect it has to be `_url`, not `_path`. See [here](https://viget.com/extend/rails-named-routes-path-vs-url)). Something like

```
# in config/routes.rb
 match '/404', to: 'errors#show', via: :all, as: :file_not_found
```

And then in your EngineController:

```
redirect_to file_not_found_url
```

Note that you can't actually specify a status of 404 for your redirect; the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) say it must be one of the `3XX` codes, which makes sense since those are the ones that correspond to a redirect.

Comment: Hmm...I see "The redirection happens as a “302 Found” header unless otherwise specified using the :status option:" in the docs, doesn't that mean you can pass a 404?

Comment: Look just a little bit lower and you'll see `Note that the status code must be a 3xx HTTP code, or redirection will not occur` haha